# How to avoid select queries in loop or make it faster?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

This part of my program executes too slow. There are measurements:

```
ELEMENTS (pairs)    ELAPSED TIME, s
12                  0.31
4692                126.24
16770               462.55
```

I think, the problem is that I am making queries in loop or SQL query is too complicated. But I don't know how to avoid this situation.

```
def set_major_minor_support(self, session, pairs):
    query = """
        SELECT count_table.current_support::NUMERIC / receipt_count_table.receipt_count::NUMERIC
        FROM
        (SELECT COUNT(*) AS current_support FROM
          (SELECT cartitem_id, receipt_id FROM cartitem WHERE product_id = {major_id}) AS A
          INNER JOIN
          (SELECT cartitem_id, receipt_id FROM cartitem WHERE product_id = {minor_id}) AS B
           ON A.receipt_id = B.receipt_id
        ) AS count_table,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) AS receipt_count FROM receipt) AS receipt_count_table;
    """

    for pair in pairs:
        major_id = pair.major_id
        minor_id = pair.minor_id

        current_query = query.format(major_id=major_id, minor_id=minor_id)

        result = session.execute(current_query).fetchone()[0]
        pair.support_major_minor = result
        print(pair.major_id, pair.support_major_minor)

    session.commit()

    return pairs
```

If it is important, 'cartitem' has 100 000 rows.

Comment: First, [you should be using SQL query parameters, not `str.format`](https://xkcd.com/327/). Besides making things insecure and brittle, you _also_ may be slowing things down (depending on which DB and which interface you're using) by making it harder to cache query plans.

Comment: Meanwhile: you've already written a complicated nested `SELECT`, so presumably you know how to use the `IN` operator with a list instead of `=` with a value; the only tricky bit is how to group the results so you get `major_id, minor_id, count` rows. If you can get everything working up to that point, then you'll have a more specific question to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How ***selective*** is the column `product_id`? That is, should it filter the data to get 50% of the rows, 5% of the rows, 0.5% of the rows?

If it's low (less than 0.5%), there's no reason this query should be slow as long as you have the appropriate indexes. You are selecting few rows, and the query should be fast.

The following index can speed up your query:

```
create index ix1 on cartitem (product_id, receipt_id, cartitem_id);
```

On the other case, if it's not really selective, then the query will be slow, since you will be processing many rows.

**Note**: the column `cartitem_id` it's not used at all on the subqueries. Why are you selecting it? To speed up the query maybe you should remove it (from the query and from the new index).

Comment: In addition to this, it might improve performance for large arrays if you create a temporary table and join with it. That would save client - server round trips.

Comment: Thanks! Index decreases elapsed time. For 4692 pairs it takes 32 s now.

Comment: Still not blazing fast. Did you find out what's the selectivity?